# Is equality of terms for "real" numbers with roots, logarithm, exponential, sin, cos, and other trigonometric operations decidable with a Turing-machine?

Tags: computer-science, lo.logic, algorithms

If yes, how? Also, I know you can't do it for arbitrary statements about real numbers, but that's not what I'm asking, and by "real" numbers, I mean the numbers constructible from 1, -, /, and the operations mentioned in the title.

Also, I don't care about numbers that can't be constructed from said operations and constant.

Comment: Note: I added the "lo.logic" and "algorithms" tags to the question.

Comment: If the answer is yes, then the next question is if it is NPC.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming [Schanuel's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture), the answer seems to be yes, according to Daniel Richardson, "How to recognize zero" *J. Symbolic Comput* **24** (1997), 627–645 ([doi:10.1006/jsco.1997.0157](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jsco.1997.0157), available [here online](http://people.bath.ac.uk/masdr/rec.ps)), in which the author defines a set of numbers he calls "elementary", which is algebraically closed and closed under exponential, logarithm and trigonometric functions, and for which equality is decidable (again, assuming Schanuel's conjecture).

Comment: The OP also asked, "If yes, how?" Even assuming that Schanuel's conjecture is true, I assume that no practical, general algorithm will never be found. Even in the much simpler case of the real field, Tarski only proved that the theory was decidable; he didn't explicitly construct a practical algorithm.

Comment: Well, Tarski did explicitly construct an algorithm (and even implemented it at some point), but it’s prohibitively slow. Better results are known, in particular, the theory of the reals is decidable in exponential space (and doubly exponential time). Its existential fragment is decidable in polynomial space, and it’s an open problem whether it’s possible to get it down to the polynomial hierarchy.

Comment: @Ben Crowell: The cited article by Richardon does give an explicit algorithm, and claims that it was implemented and is actually usable.

Comment: @BenCrowell, I think the algorithm for deciding $a=b$ is obvious: simultaneously generate more and more identities to prove the equality, and calculate $a$ and $b$ with more and more accuracy to prove the inequality. If all goes well, exactly one of the two will work.

Comment: There is a catch that an input expression might not represent a number, e.g. if it contains a division by (non-obvious) zero, or $\log$ of zero, and it is not clear how numerical algorithms would behave in those cases (presumably, they would be stuck trying to compute even a single digit of the result). But if we also simultaneously search for identities proving that the corresponding subexpression is zero, those cases will be eventually detected.