# Is it always possible to calculate the limit of an elementary function?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-calculus, differential-algebra

I already asked this question on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2691331/is-it-always-possible-to-calculate-the-limit-of-an-elementary-function but as I received no answer; maybe it is not as obvious as I originally thought.

The precise formulation of my question is: define an "strong elementary function" by only admitting rational for the "constant function" in the usual definition of "elementary" function (see for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). Let $a$ be an "elementary real" if the constant function $f(x)=a$ is a strong elementary function. With this definition some non rational reals are elementary (for example $\pi=4⋅arctan(1)$); but there are reals that are not elementary. Now let $f(x)$ be a strong elementary function defined in an open interval of an elementary real $a$ with the possible exception of $a$. Suppose that
$lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)$
exists. Is this limit necessarily an elementary real?

The idea behind this question is this: it seems that "limits" can always be calculated with some simple tricks (Hospital rule, etc...) in elementary calculus; but is there a general argument that shows that it is always possible? (the precise formulation of the question does not ask for an algorithm, I expect a positive answer to be constructive, but that is not entirely clear).

Update: clarification of the notion of elementary functions.

**Definition**
By function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$; I mean a partial function.
The class of (strong) elementary functions is the smallest class of functions such that:

1. the constant function $f(x)=1$ is elementary.
2. if $f$ and $g$ are elementary; so is $f+g$; $f-g$; $f\cdot g$; $f/g$. (the domain of $f/g$ is ${\rm dom}(f)\cap {\rm dom}(g)\cap \{x \ | \ g(x)\neq 0\}$.
3. if $n$ is a natural number; $f(x)=x^n$ and $f(x)=\sqrt[n]{x}$ are elementary; the domain of the later is $\mathbb{R}^+$.
4. $\sin$, $\cos$, $\tan$ are elementary
5. $\arcsin$, $\arccos$ and $\arctan$ are elementary. ($\arcsin:[-1\ 1]\rightarrow[-\pi\ \pi]$; $\arccos(x)={\pi\over 2}-\arcsin(x)$; $\arctan: ]-\infty\ +\infty[\rightarrow]-\pi\ \pi[$)
6. $\exp$ is elementary.
7. $\ln$ is elementary. ($\ln: \mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$).
8. if $f$ and $g$ are elementary; so is $f\circ g$; the domain of the latter is $\{x\ | \ x\in{\rm dom}(g) \wedge g(x)\in{\rm dom}(f)\}$.

I have not tried to avoid redundancy but 
note that the point 3 is not redundant because of the domain of the functions considered; for example $f(x)=x^2$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ but $f(x)=\exp(2\cdot\ln(x))$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}_0^+$. Also $\sqrt[n]{x}$ is defined for $x=0$ but not $\exp(\frac{\ln(x)}{n})$.

I think this is the class of functions we consider in the Risch algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) except that I do not take all constant functions as elementary; that would obviously make no sense for my question.

I hope I have not missed something obvious. I do not think a small modification of my definition will make any difference; if it is it would be interesting to discus.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the "elementary" class is not supposed to be closed under local inversion. I don't know if it matters, though.

Comment: In your limit, $x\to a$ you admit all complex $x$ or only real? If complex,  then $a$ can be only an algebraic singularity (a branch point  pole, no worse), and then the limit can be always found by l'Hospital rule.

Comment: @ Alexandre Eremenko. My question concerns the reals. A comment on the original question asked on "math stack exchange" already did notice that the answer is true in the complex plane. But this result does not appear to transfer for real defined functions. Many "counter-example in analysis" do not exists anyway in complex analysis (smooth non-analytical function, etc.)

Comment: @oliver: If you are interested in real limits, see my answer part 2. However I am not 100% sure about the answer with complex limits. A singularity of an elementary function may not be isolated, so classification "removable, essential, ramification point" is not applicable. One needs some more sophisticated argument.

Comment: You might be interested in the following related question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/118972

Comment: As someone rather ignorant both in analysis and in logic, I find this question and its answers 1) very interesting and 2) quite mysterious. Can someone clarify for instance how the answer of @IgorRivin is compatible with Schanuel's conjecture in the MO question quoted by @Gro-Tsen? I'm guessing that all potential zeros of polynomial and sine functions are not elementary zeros in the sense of Richardson. Am I right?

Comment: @Olivier I too am confused by the apparent conflict between IgorRivin's answer and the Richardson paper.  I think the trick is that one merely purports to decide equality whereas Wang's paper refers to statements with an existential quantifier, but then I'm confused by the relation to your problem.  I wish someone could clarify what can and what cannot be done (maybe this is grounds for a new question).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen *but then I'm confused by the relation to your problem* just to clarify: olivier asked this question, while I'm Olivier (not at all the same MO user).

Comment: @Olivier Oh now this is getting even more confusing.  I give up!  

Answer (score 33):

EDITED. I use the definition of "elementary function" of Liouville and Ritt (also repeated in Wikipedia). See Ritt's papers in TAMS 25 (1923) 211-222, and
TAMS 27 (1925) 68-90. This definition includes the analytic continuation through removable singularities. These elementary functions are analytic and can be multi-valued. Of course, other definitions are possible, and the answer will depend on the definition. Your new definition of "elementary functions" is close to the classes
of "elementary functions" and 
"naive elementary functions", defined by Laczkovich and Ruzsa except that they allow all constants in the definition, and you allow only $1$.
The difference between their classes is in where exactly is
$\arcsin$ defined. So it is important to state a more precise definition.

Ref. M. Laczkovich and I. Ruzsa,  Elementary and integral elementary functions,
Illinois J. Math., 44, 1 (2000) 161-182.

For elementary functions in the sense of Liouville and Ritt, the answer is probably different, depending on what you mean by the limit.
(Existing of a limit as $x\to a$ when $x$ is complex is a much stronger condition then existence of a limit when $x$ is real).

1. Complex limits. The answer seems to be yes. What follows is a heuristic argument. Elementary functions are analytic, with at most countably many singularities.
   So when the finite limit exists, the singularity is removable or a ramification point. Expanding everything in power series (perhaps with fractional powers), we can compute the limit. The coefficients of these power series are elementary constants, because they are expressed in terms of derivatives. So the answer is probably yes, if we mean complex limits. (This is heuristic because singularities can accumulate so one needs more careful argument).
2. Real limits. The answer seems to be no. Consider a trigonometric sum 
   $$f(t)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\exp(\lambda_jit),\quad i=\sqrt{-1},$$
   and assume that it has no real zeros. Suppose that the $\lambda_j$ are real "elementary constants" but incommensurable. Then $f(t)=r(t)\exp(i\phi(t))$, where $r(t)>0$ and $\phi$ is a well-defined elementary real function (in the sense of Liouville and Ritt). The limit
   $$m:=\lim_{t\to+\infty}\phi(t)/t$$ always exists: this is the celebrated Mean Motion Theorem. There is a formula for this limit due to A. Wintner:
   $$m=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jW_j,\quad\mbox{where}\quad W_j=\int_{T^n}\Re\frac{a_j\exp(i\theta_j)}{\sum_ka_k\exp(i\theta_k)}d\theta_1\ldots d\theta_n,$$
   where $T^n=[0,2\pi]^n$.
   These integrals are probably not "elementary constants", Weyl computed them:
   $$W_j=a_j\int_0^\infty J_1(a_jx)\prod_{k\neq j}J_0(a_kx)\, dx.$$

where $J$ are Bessel functions. Again, this argument is incomplete, because one has to
prove that the $W_j$ can indeed be "non-elementary" constants. These 
"elementary constants" are discussed in [this paper](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)
and the author writes that no single explicit example of non-elementary number is known! We know that they exist only because the set of elementary numbers is countable.

But at least the argument shows that to compute a limit of an elementary function
it is not enough to use such things as l'Hopital rule, one may need to compute definite integrals.

References on the mean motion theorem: S. Sternberg, Celestial Mechanics, Part I, Benjamin, 1969, H. Weyl, Mean motion I, Amer. J. Math., 60, 4(1938) 889-896.

UPDATE. For any counterexample to your conjecture, there is a formidable difficulty that not a single explicit number in known to be non-elementary.
Therefore I propose to modify the question:

> Let $f(x,a)$ be an elementary
>   function of two variables. Is it true that $g(a)=\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x,a)$
>   is an elementary function of $a$, provided that the limit exists for 
>   all $a$ on some interval?

This seems to be in the same spirit, but more accessible than what you asked.
Because we know quite a lot about elementary functions but really nothing
about elementary numbers.

For this question, perhaps it is possible to prove rigorously that the answer is no, with
Liouville-Ritt elementary functions. But so far I was unable to
prove that $W_j$ is non-elementary as a function of, say $a_1$,
when $n\geq 3$. (When $n\leq 3$ it is elementary, and it was known that
the mean motion has an elementary expression when $n\leq 3$ (Bohl).

With "purely real elementary functions", in the spirit of your definition,
the answer is still no, if we allow the $\arcsin{}$ in your definition
to have the domain $(-1,1)$. Then all elementary functions are analytic (as compositions of analytic functions),
but we have a non-analytic limit: ($x\to+\infty$ along the positive ray)
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\arctan(ax)=\frac{\pi}{2}{\mathrm{sgn}}(a),\quad \lim_{x\to+\infty}(1+a^x)^{1/x}.$$
If you allow $\arcsin$ on $[-1,1]$ then elementary functions can be discontinuous like $\arcsin(\sin x)$, and the above counterexample does
not work.

If you remove trigonometric functions from your class, the answer is yes. And this was essentially proved by Hardy in
his book Orders of Infinity.

Comment: I may miss the obvious, but how do you get $f(t)=r(t)\exp(i\phi(t))$, could you maybe give a simple explanatory example.

Comment: @olivier : Really?  You don't recognize representing $f$ in polar coordinates?

Comment: But how do you ensure that the functions are elementary? OK for $r(t)$ but how do you get $\phi(t)$? You can't make piecewise definition. You use what is commonly known as $atan2(x,y) = \pm arctan(y/x)$ plus the special treatment for x=0. That's not elementary.

Comment: $\phi(t)={\mathrm{Im}}\log f(t)$, this permits an analytic continuation along the real axis as long as $\phi(t)\neq 0$, and this is certainly an elementary function.

Comment: There will be no harm if you just replace $\phi(t)=\log f(t)$, as it differs from the old $\phi$ by a bounded summand.

Comment: @oliver: You do not give a definition of elementary function, referring to Wikipedia. Wikipedia does not have a precise definition, but gives complex logarithm as an example. It refers to Ritt's papers, and I follow the Ritt definition.

Comment: For the elementary function, I had in mind real functions only. My initial idea was over the reals only; with the definition given by the point 1-9 mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function except that I initially only recognize constant rational as elementary (and not arbitrary constant). Note that I am increasingly convinced that you are right.

Comment: @oliver: My function $\phi$ is real. But to write its expression in terms of  exponential and log I have to use analytic continuation. Otherwise, if you wish to restrict strictly to the real domain, you have huge difficulties with domains of definition when you try to define your class. These difficulties will invalidate most theorems about elementary functions. For example $\arctan(1/x)$, is it defined and continuous in a neighborhood of $0$? I adhere to the point of view that $0$ is a removable singularity of this function, where the branches are smoothly connected.

Comment: @olivier: Just think on this example carefully: $\arctan(1/x)$ What is the domain? It surely must contain $R\backslash\{0\}$. Now, how exactly you want to define it? As having a jump at $0$? How much jump? It seems that the only reasonable definition is such that it has no jump, but is infinitely-valued.

Comment: I do not claim that complex or multi-valued functions are not interesting. But you seem to completely disregard pure real functions in a strict sense. Multi valued functions is a concept that is not so natural either. They are usually not accepted as "functions" outside complex analysis (just read the definition of function as stated here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)). How would you define a multi-valued function in general? What would it mean for these general multi-valued functions to be continuous? integrable? etc.

Comment: How would you define (for example): $\int_0^1 \arctan(x) dx$ if $arctan$ is multi-valued? We use these expression all the times, it is supposed to be well defined. If you look in text over real analysis, $arctan$ is defined carefully (the image is $]-\pi\ \pi[$).

Comment: @oliver: "multivalued function" is not a function, therefore you cannot integrate it. What you can integrate is a branch. There are infinitely many branches of arctan on the real line, they are different functions and each of them you can integrate. "Elementary functions" (as defined by Liouville and Ritt) are multivalued. If you propose some other approach, please give a precise definition of an "elementary function". Explain exactly what you mean by $x^{1/3}$ to begin with, and then think of $\arctan(1/x)$.

Comment: @oliver: once you give an exact definition of "pure real elementary function", I will address your question again, with this new definition.

Comment: I hope the definition is now clear (see the updated question)

Comment: Regarding the definition of "elementary real," I gave one possible definition in this paper: http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf I think that this definition is close to, if not exactly the same as, what olivier wants. The definition has the advantage of sidestepping some of the issues about domains of definition of elementary functions. On the other hand, difficulties remain; e.g., it remains unclear whether $\gamma$ is an elementary real.

Comment: It seems indeed that the "closed form" real are exactly what I call "elementary reals". Also the general idea as given in the introduction. I want to calculate the limit of a function in a closed-form. I initially thought that it was always possible; but although not yet completely clear;  the answer of Alexandre Eremenko make me doubt it. Proving that a given real is not "elementary" or in "closed-form" might indeed be difficult.

Comment: @oliver: your definition is still incomplete: you have to specify the domains of log, arcsin, arctan, etc. Or explain what you mean by them.

Comment: But this is the usual domain as described in elementary calculus books; see for
example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions. $\arctan:
]-\infty\ \infty[ \rightarrow ]-\pi\ \pi[$; $\ln \mathbb{R^+} \rightarrow
    \mathbb{R^+}$; $\tan: \{x\in\mathbb{R}\ |\ \forall k\in \mathbb{Z} \ x\neq
    k\pi\}$. You can define $\sin$, $\cos$, $\arcsin$, $\arccos$ by means of these with common identities. I don't think it will matter as long as we use common real functions.

Comment: The definition of elementary function of "Laczkovich and I. Ruzsa" (see the proposed answer of Alexandre Eremenko) is very close to my definition. The elementary constant would be the same but there can be variation of the domain of the functions considered. I would be very surprised if it make a real difference in the end.

Comment: @oliver: if you read Laczkovich and Ruzsa attentively, you see that there is a great difference between arcsin on [-1,1] and arcsin on (-1,1). Then, the domain of a function (with your definition) can be a complicated set, much more complicated than an interval.

Comment: @Alexandre Eremeno. I have notice it and I agree with it. However I have suppose that the function is well defined on an open interval around the elementary real $a$. So $f(x)$ is defined in an interval $]a \ b[$ for some $b$. This is the reason I expect my definition to be not entirely different, but I agree this is not completely clear.

Comment: What is $m$ for $a_1=\lambda_2=1$, $a_2=\lambda_1=\sqrt{2}$?  This looks like a good test case.  I can calculate $$\phi(t)=\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(\sqrt{2}t)+\sqrt{2}\sin(t)}{ \cos(\sqrt{2}t)+\sqrt{2}\cos(t)}\right) + \pi\#(\{\cos(\sqrt{2}u)+\sqrt{2}\cos(u)=0, 0<u<t\})$$.  Then I see $\phi(t)/t$ staying close to 1, but I haven't been able to calculate the integrals.

Comment: @Matt F.: Two and three incommensurable frequencies lead to elementary integrals. You have to start with $n=4$ to obtain a complicated constant.

Comment: Your update -- about functions rather than numbers, with a different set of functions, and motivation that requires some background -- is interesting and different enough to be moved to a new question.  I'd be happy to comment on it in that context!

Comment: @Matt F.: OK, this discussion becomes too long. I will start a new question.

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko I am perplex when you say that the answer is ``yes'' without trigonometric
function. We can define $f(x,a)=\exp({ -1 \over x^2+a^2})$. If we take
$g(a)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}f(x,a)$, we get $g(a)=\exp({-1\over a^2})$,
with $g(0)=0$. This function is known to be non analytic (at 0).

Comment: @oliver: It is not analytic at zero but it is an elementary function.

Comment: Is it? It is elementary for ${\rm dom}(g)=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ but if we say $g(0)=0$, it does not seems to be elementary and that is the function we get. I think that we can (easily) show that if an elementary  function $g$ is defined on an open interval then it is analytic on that interval, because that's the case for the "primitive" elementary functions.

Comment: @oliver: as I said many times, this depends on the EXACT definition of "elementary function". The definition in your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 6):

In fact, zero-equivalence for combinations of polynomial and sine functions is undecidable, which means that it is undecidable whether the limit is zero in that setting (This goes back to at least Paul Wang's 1974 paper The undecidability of the existence of zeros of real elementary functions).

Comment: Yes, it is undecidable whether the limit is 0, and I suppose undecidable whether the limit exists. But this is a somewhat different problem: we want to know: IF the limit exists is it elementary.

Comment: If it is undecidable whether the limit is 0; then it is undecidable whether the limit exists since obviously $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)\neq 0$ iff $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} {1\over f(x)}$ exists. But I agree this is a different (although interesting) problem.