# Guaranteed correct digits of elementary expressions

Tags: algorithms, na.numerical-analysis, decidability

Let $E$ be the set of *elementary expressions*, defined as the smallest set of mathematical expressions such that $1 \in E$, and if $a,b \in E$ then $a + b$, $a - b$, $ab$, $a/b$, $\exp(a)$, $\log(a)$ all belongs to $E$ (note that expressions such as $a/0$ or $\log(0)$ are fine, although they do not have a numerical value).

This problems often pop ups:

**Problem.** Given an expression $f$ in $E$ and a natural number $n$, find the first $n$ decimal digits of the numerical evaluation of $f$ (real and complex part).

Note that $E$ contains expressions for $e = \exp(1)$, $i = \exp(\log(-1)/2)$, $\pi = -i\log(-1)$, and many "elementary" mathematical constants.
Also, assume a [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) evaluation for expressions like $1/0$.

My questions are the following:

1. Is this problem decidable? I found that [Richardson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem) establishes the undecidability of a similar problem.
2. If the problem is decidable, is there a known algorithm and some (at least partial) implementation of it?
3. If the problem is undecidable, what is the main obstruct and are there some ways to go around it? Again implementation of (heuristic?) algorithms are welcome.

Thanks

**Update.** The current answers solve the question if the problem is decidable (yes, but under [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture)). The only thing that prevents me from accepting an answer, is that I would like to know about implementations of the algorithm. Since I often encounter this problem in practice, is there some software that (assuming Schanuel's conjecture) I can run to solve the problem for a certain expression? (Of course I can do my own reasoning about the number of correct digits given by certain software and how the errors propagate, but I would like something that automatically do that.)

**Second update.** In light of Aurel's comments, I point out that the software [Calcium](https://fredrikj.net/calcium/) seems to do the job. More precisely, according to the documentation, the function

`char *ca_get_decimal_str(const ca_t x, slong digits, ulong flags, ca_ctx_t ctx)`

returns a decimal approximation of **x** with precision up to **digits**. The output is guaranteed to be correct within 1 ulp in the returned digits, but the number of returned digits may be smaller than digits if the numerical evaluation does not succeed.

Comment: Doesn't Richardson's theorem immediately give that your problem isn't decidable, with $\sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}2$?

Comment: Also see [Tarski's exponential function problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_exponential_function_problem)

Comment: [Related question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/118972/17064) about deciding equality of such problems, the answer to which implies, if I am mot mistaken, that, *assuming Schanuel's conjecture*, the answer to your question will be positive (i.e., computing digits is decidable).

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This is an interesting question, which turns out to be equivalent to a difficult open problem, and although it is easily confused with Richardson's theorem, it is a distinct problem.

Comment: About your update: you may be interested in [Calcium](https://fredrikj.net/calcium/). Although it does not (yet?) have a complete implementation of Richardson's algorithm, it can decide some nontrivial equalities.

Comment: About your second update, are you saying that Calcium returns guarranteed correct digits, or rather just that the numerical value is accurate to the ulp? These two things are not the same, since the value 3.26999999, for example, is within ulp of 3.27000000, but the earlier digits were not correct. This is a key difference discussed in the answers.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464134/guaranteed-correct-digits-of-elementary-expressions#comment1205977_464134), this seems like a strange example to pick: $3.26\overline 9$ is exactly equal to $3.27$, so it seems strange to declare that a truncation of the former has the wrong decimal digits.  Is it universally agreed in such questions that, if a terminating decimal expansion is possible, then it is the correct one, and the other is wrong?  (I see that this was also discussed by [@‍AlexandreEremenko](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1205356).)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I do not think that Calcium returns guaranteed digits. But it can perform some nontrivial equality tests. For numerical computations, it relies on [Arb](https://fredrikj.net/arb/), which always outputs a guaranteed enclosure for the correct result.

Comment: @LSpice, you misunderstood my example. Perhaps the true actual value would be 3.269999999234 etc., but the point is that if Calcium returned 3.270000 it would be highly accurate, but the digits would not be correct. That is, having an accurate result is not the same as having digits correct to that place. Or similarly, if the true value was 3.27000000023, then 3.269999999 would also be highly accurate, but with wrong digits.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464134/guaranteed-correct-digits-of-elementary-expressions#comment1205989_464134), I see; I did misunderstand the example.  Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a certain confusion in the answers, so let me try to dispel this confusion.

There are two different issues here.  One is “computing an approximation with arbitrary precision” and one is “computing correct digits”.

The first, “computing an approximation with arbitrary precision”, is certainly possible algorithmically (*proviso* the quantity is indeed a real or complex number), as Alexandre Eremenko points out in his answer.  However, as Joel David Hamkins points out in a comment to this answer, computing arbitrarily precise approximations (≈being a computable real number) is *not* the same as computing guaranteed correct digits, essentially because deciding whether a computable real number is $\geq 0$ or $\leq 0$ (even if both answers are deemed acceptable in case of exact equality) is not decidable.

However, for the specific numbers being considered here, it turns out that equality *is* decidable, **if** we assume Schanuel's conjecture holds, as I explain in the answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118972/is-equality-of-terms-for-real-numbers-with-roots-logarithm-exponential-sin) (this is also [a result by Richardson](https://doi.org/10.1006/jsco.1997.0157), but this one is positive).  Now if we can decide equality and we can compute with arbitrary precision, then we can indeed compute guaranteed correct digits.  So the answer to the question is positive *provided* we assume Schanuel's conjecture.  More precisely, there is a (fairly explicit) algorithm which will compute guaranteed correct digits if it terminates, and which will always terminate if Schanuel's conjecture holds.

Comment: Gro-Tsen, are you saying that my answer is incorrect or confused? It seems that the digit problem is Turing equivalent to the constant problem, and this is open, although you point out that both would be decidable under Schanuel's conjecture.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I'm not saying either way, because I'm not sure after reading the MathWorld and Wikipedia articles what the constant problem actually says (specifically, are there indeterminates in the expression or is it just about real numbers?). But note that there's no contradiction between “it's decidable under Schanuel's conjecture” and “it's an open question whether it's decidable”. (At best, the MathWorld and Wikipedia article are confusing for not mentioning — or comparing with — Richardson's positive result which I cited.)

Comment: Oh, I agree with that point. But isn't it clear that the constant problem is exactly the case where there are no indeterminates? This was the confusion (between the constant problem and Richardson's theorem) that I had taken myself to be dispelling.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins The MathWorld and Wikipedia articles suggest that the “constant problem” allows “taking limits”, which suggests that there must be some kind of indeterminate on which to take the limit. But again, I just don't understand what they're saying. However, Richardson's paper is pretty clear that he has a positive result, conditional to Schanuel's conjecture, for deciding equality of “elementary numbers”, which are an algebraically closed field closed under $\exp$, $\sin$ and $\cos$ (and, if I understand his definitions, $\log$ as well).

Comment: Yes, the post there is not as clear as I had thought at first. I had taken it to be the same problem that you are describing as solved under Schanuel's conjecture, since indeed this problem is a very natural weakening of the problem in the original Richardson's theorem.

Comment: Meanwhile, it might be good to mention that Schanuel's conjecture is often seen as extremely strong. It has many powerful consequences, which unify known theorems, but do number theorists/model theorists generally think it is true?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins My understanding is that Schanuel's conjecture is generally believed to be true but so vastly out of reach of current techniques that it is something of a holy grail. (A similar “very general, generally believed but ridiculously out of reach” conjecture would be [Schinzel's hypothesis H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H).)

Answer (score 11):

This problem is Turing equivalent to the [constant problem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConstantProblem.html) (see also [Wikipedia-constant problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_problem)), but it is open whether this problem is decidable.

The constant problem is the problem of determining whether a given constant expression $E$ (in a suitable language) is zero.

This is different from Richardson's theorem, which in contrast is concerned with the problem of determining whether a given expression $E(x)$ with free variable $x$ is the zero function, that is, zero for all values of $x$. Richardson's theorem shows that this problem is not computably decidable.

Your digit problem is at least as hard as the constant problem, since as Kostya mentions in his answer, a given constant expression $E$ is zero if and only if $1-E^2$ starts with 1.0.

Conversely, the constant problem is at least as hard as the digit problem. To see this, notice first that the digit problem is computable from the order-relation problem, determining whether $E<F$ for constant expressions. This is because you can learn the digits of $E$ by comparing it with suitable rational expressions. And the $E<F$ problem is equivalent to deciding positivity $0<E$. But with an oracle for the constant problem, given $E$ we can first decide whether $E=0$ or not, and if not, compute approximations well enough to determine the sign. (Thanks for the comment of Aurel.)

So your problem is equivalent to the constant problem. But according to Wolfram, it is open whether the constant problem is computably decidable.

Comment: Perhaps a clever person can show that the digit problem is Turing equivalent to the constant problem?

Comment: Can't you do something like this? Suppose you can solve the constant problem. Then you can decide the sign of any expression: first test for zero, and if not zero compute a good enough approximation to determine the sign. Finally the $k$-th digit (given the previous ones) being equal to a certain value is equivalent to a certain inequality about the expression.

Comment: Yes, I think that works! (I was also just thinking along similar lines.)

Comment: Do we determine the sign of an expression $E$ by asking whether the imaginary part of $\log(E)$ is $0$? Would twice the imaginary part be $E-\exp(-\log(E))$? Nope. How could we extract it ?

Comment: These are all computable numbers, so we can compute their values to within any desired accuracy $\epsilon$. This doesn't necessarily give exact digits, though, since we could be on one side or another of a rational $10^{-n}$. But if a computable real number is not exactly $0$, then we can bound it on one side or the other with the approximations.

Comment: What procedure would you use to assert every bound you need? It looks like the initial problem to me.

Comment: No, it is computable. Given $E$, I first check whether $E=0$. If not, I successively compute approximations, within 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, etc. These approximations are known exactly, but only guarranteed to be within the desired $1/2^k$. But if $E$ really is positive, then eventually I will find a positive approximation with accuracy forcing it to be positive. And similar for negative $E$. The importance of knowing $E\neq 0$ is that in general, if $E=0$, all the approximations will be close to zero in such a way that you will never be able to tell if it is positive or negative.

Comment: @ClaudeChaunier Or perhaps you are simply asking why these numbers are computable numbers? This is because of the kind of reasoning in Alexandre's answer, which gives approximate values to the expressions as accurate as desired, that is, within a known $\epsilon$. The key fact to keep in mind, though, is that having accurate approximations is not the same as having exact digits, since perhaps the value is close to a boundary where the digits flip over with carries, and you won't know yet which side you're on.

Comment: These are continuous functions, and we can compute with rational approximations. All such expressions are computable real numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number

Comment: Is this related to the real world? Should I trust CAS about real tasks?

Comment: If $E= 0.01 exp(log(−1)/2) $ Then $1-E^2 = 1.0001$ I'm not sure if that is problematic for you assertion that $E=0$ if $1-E^2$ starts with $1.0$

Comment: Of course I was thinking of real values only.

Answer (score 5):

Edited after the comment of Joel David Hamkins. The "correct $n$-th digit of a real number,
of of real and imaginary part of a complex number is
ill defined. For example, what is the $n$-th digit of the number 1=0.999999...? What is the "correct 5-th digit"?

But you can approximate your numbers with any given accuracy, and there are simple algorithms for this. The algorithms for $a\pm b$, $ab$ and $a/b$ we study in elementary school while for $\exp(a),\log a$ one can use power series, or rational approximation.

The difference with Richardson's theorem is that he considers exact equality, while you ask only about $n$ digits. So you cannot always determine that such an expression is $=0$, but you can determine whether the first 100 digits are $0$.

Moreover, for all these functions there exist algorithms which work with polynomial speed in $n$, even with the speed $n^{1+\epsilon}$. For addition/subtraction this is evident, for multiplication/division these are fast multiplication algorithms (based of fast Fourier transform), while for $\exp$ and $\log$ these are algorithms based on AGM.

See, for example, Donald Newman, Rational approximation versus fast computer methods. Lectures on approximation and value distribution, pp. 149–174, Sém. Math. Sup., 79, Presses Univ. Montréal, Montreal, QC, 1982,

where all mentioned algorithms are explained.

Comment: For exact digits, you can't even add $a+b$. If you know lots of digits for $a$ and $b$ exactly, then to get exact digits for $a+b$, you might have to know whether there is a carry or not, which might not yet be revealed in what you know about $a$ and $b$ (and might never be revealed). e.g. $a=0.444444\ldots$ and $b=0.555555\ldots$. This issue is related to a certain error that Turing had made in his 1936 paper about computable numbers. See https://jdh.hamkins.org/alan-turing-on-computable-numbers/.

Comment: By "$n$ exact digits" I mean that you can compute the number with accuracy $10^{-n}$. You are right, of course, one cannot literally obtain exact digits. Actually since 0.9999...=1, is the same real number, "exact digits of a real number are not even defined!

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko "exact digits of a real number are not even defined!" I entirely disagree with this assertion. The decimal representation of real numbers can be uniquely defined by not allowing an infinite sequence of 9 digits at the end.

Comment: rosan98: You can interpret my answer in either way. See comment of Joel Hamkins.